# How to get index from a Model Class iteration in a Playframework Scala Template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying a simple thing with the TODO tutorial.

I want to show the task list in a table but I can't find a way to get the index in the iteration.

```
@tasks.map { task =>
                <tr>
                    <td><!-- DISPLAY INDEX HERE --></td>
                    <td>
                        @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id.get)) {
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary remove_task" value="-">
                        }
                        @task.label
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `zipWithIndex`. For example:

```
scala> List("A","B","C")
res4: List[java.lang.String] = List(A, B, C)

scala> res4.zipWithIndex
res5: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((A,0), (B,1), (C,2))
```

Your final code would be, notice I renamed the `task` variable:

```
@tasks.zipWithIndex.map { tuple =>
                <tr>
                    <td>tuple._2</td>
                    <td>
                        @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(tuple._1.id.get)) {
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary remove_task" value="-">
                        }
                        @tuple._1.label
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@tasks.zipWithIndex.map { case (task, index) => ... }`